# How to append tables "Sideways" in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

What i have is approximately 15 tables, each with about 10 columns and almost 1 million rows of data.

All the 15 tables have the same primary keys I can use to join them by.

For example..
Table 1 - Columns A B C D E 
Table 2 - Columns A B F G H 
Table 3 - Columns A B I J K 
Table 4 - Columns A B L M N 
etc.. where A & B are the primary keys

What I need would be one huge table that looks like this.. 
mainTable - Columns A B C D E F G ... M N

Right now, what I have done is:
- Start off with Table 1 as my "main" table 
- Alter the table to add all the columns.. (i.e. F G H .. L M N)
- use an UPDATE command to fill in the "main" table

```
update mainTable set 
 F = a.F,
 G = a.G,
 H = a.H
from mainTable left join Table2 a on
mainTable.A = a.A  and 
mainTable.B = a.B 

(rinse and repeat for each of the 15 tables)
```

This seems to work, just that it's horribly inefficient. It takes ages to join just one table..

Is there an alternative/faster method of performing this task?

Comment: Why are you using a `LEFT JOIN`? This will force the values to `NULL` if they corresponding Keys don't exist in the Table2 *(And Table3, etc)*. Is that correct? Also, do you know for certain that each key from `mainTable` only exists *(at most)* once, in the other tables?  Next *(and also partially in answer to the last question)*, do you have indexes and/or Primary Key Constraints enforced on all the tables?  Ensuring speedy joins?  Finally, is there a reason you are unable to do them all in one update with `main LEFT JOIN a LEFT JOIN b LEFT JOIN c etc, etc`?

Comment: Hi Dems, I am sure that the corresponding keys exist in all the tables, and that the key in mainTable is unique. Primary key constraints aren't enforced in this table, and I'm not too sure what you mean by speedy joins. I could do it all in one massive update, but when I try it with just 2 tables, it already takes 15-25 minutes to complete the update.. which is why I'm here looking for a more effective alternative

Comment: What I mean is that without an Index or a Primary Key Constraint, on each of your tables, the joins will be extremely slow.  It's akin to ripping a million pages out of a book and asking you to match them to a million pages ripped out of another book.  If they're put into the same order it's a trivial job.  If they're scattered aroudn (no index or PK constraint) then you'll go insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates are often slower than inserts. Rather create a new table and insert all the data into it.

Comment: What if there are foreign key constraints referencing that table, etc?

Comment: Change the foreign keys to reference the new table. Then replace the old tables with views.

Comment: i tried creating a table and inserting, and a problem with the Primary file group max size occurred. (I'm using sql server express). Anyway, what I did eventually was to just SELECT all the fields across the 15 tables and right click > Save results as > into a CSV file, which I then imported back into a new database, into a newly created "main" table. Still importing as I type this, hope there are no errors this time!

Answer (score 1):

One option I can think of:

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  A <some format> NOT NULL,
  B <some format> NOT NULL,
  C <some format> NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_data_C DEFAULT (' '),
  D <some format> NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_data_D DEFAULT (' '),
  ...
  N <some format> NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_data_N DEFAUT (' ')
)
```

Right, now you have a table with all necessary columns. As the inserts don't interfere with each other, just insert all import data into the big table. One thing to check is space as this table is necessarily big at the end with millions of rows.

Then to finish it "move" the data from table data to table main using the GROUP BY clause:
    INSERT INTo main
    SELECT A, B, Max(C), Max(D), Max(E), Max(F)... Max(N)
    FROM data
    GROUP BY A, B

Now this is probably a resource hog but might still perform faster than the updates. The idea behind it is to speed the data gathering process and then when all of the data is in one place move the data correctly together. As the other columns are by default blank (or one space) the Max function will take the data from whichever column it actually was imported from.

Comment: Interesting idea there.. I'll try Anthony's suggestion first as it requires less steps. My original method of using UPDATE seems to be getting slower exponentially with each table added..

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a select into like this:

```
    SELECT 
        T1.A, T1.B, T1.C,
        T2.D, T2.E, T2.F,
        T3.G, T3.H
    INTO NewTable 
    FROM 
      T1 
      inner join T2 on T1.A = T2.A and T1.B = T2.B
      inner join T3 on T1.A = T3.A and T1.B = T3.B
            ORDE BY A,B -- If this will become your PK
```

Then you just have to alter the table to add the required indexes:

```
  ALTER TABLE NewTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_NewTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (A,B)
```

This will work only if all the tables have the same combination of A,B. If this varies from table to table you need a different solution:

```
    SELECT 
        T1.A, T1.B, T1.C,
        T2.D, T2.E, T2.F,
        T3.G, T3.H
    INTO NewTable 
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT A,B FROM
     (SELECT A,B FROM T1
      UNION SELECT A,B FROM T2
      UNION SELECT A,B FROM T3) ALL) T0
      inner join T1 on T0.A = T1.A and T0.B = T1.B
      inner join T2 on T0.A = T2.A and T0.B = T2.B
      inner join T3 on T0.A = T3.A and T0.B = T3.B
```